# The HTML onClick does not work for one user on his MAC but works fine if he logs onto someone else's MAC

Tags: html, google-apps-script

As the developer of the GAS code, the initial HTML dialog appears and functions properly. The html source for EnhancementsDialog.html is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function onFailure(error) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = "ERROR: " + error.message;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      .button {
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
      p.Lato{font-size: 20px; font-family: Lato,Arial,serif;}
    </style>
    <p class="Lato">
    Please click the appropriate button for the type of Customization to be added.
    </p>
    <pre>
      <input type="button" class="button" value="EVENT" 
        onclick="google.script.run.Add_Custom_Action('EVENT');
        google.script.host.close);"
      >
      <input type="button" class="button" value="ENHANCEMENT" 
        onclick="google.script.run.Add_Custom_Action('ENHANCEMENT');
        google.script.host.close;"
      > 
     </pre>
</html>
```

The html is invoked from a pull down menu on a spreadsheet which calls this function:

```
    function Add_Custom() {
      var widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("EnhancementsDialog.html");
      //widget.setWidth(600);
      widget.setHeight(175);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(widget,"dineDK");
    } //end function Add_Custom
```

The buttons "EVENT" and "ENHANCEMENT" work for me and others except for one user on any browser he uses. Is there any specific system setting that would prevent the 'onClick' from working? The execution log shows me no information.

I am at a loss as to how to investigate this further. Help!

Comment: There is no body closing tag

Comment: This `google.script.host.close` should be this `google.script.host.close();`

Comment: Your two input tags on the bottom are not closed

Comment: @Cooper Yes they are.

Comment: @Rob No. They are not.

Comment: @Cooper Please explain. I see `<input type="button" class="button" value="EVENT" onclick="google.script.run.Add_Custom_Action('EVENT'); google.script.host.close);" >` which is clearly closed.

Comment: @Rob `<input type="button" class="button" value="EVENT" onclick="google.script.run.Add_Custom_Action('EVENT'); google.script.host.close);" />` now it's closed

Comment: @Cooper HTML elements do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification. [It does not mark a tag as self-closing](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-in-void-element-start-tags-do-not-mark-the-start-tags-as-self-closing). In fact, [it can cause issues](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-directly-preceded-by-unquoted-attribute-values) Putting the slash there is allowed but it has no meaning, it does nothing, and browsers ignore it.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that.  Interestingly enough HtmlService does not classify it as malformed.

Comment: Thank you for the commentary. I have made the code aesthetically correct. The one user still cannot execute the code. Cannot determine what stops the HTML pop-ups from working. He reinstalled Chrome and it worked for a few days and then stopped working for him.